# Where can I read plot summaries for each chapter of the Umineko manga, specifically Umineko Chiru the answer arcs? Or for the VNs?

Tags: umineko-when-they-cry

For the Umineko anime, of course you can see the plot [previews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Umineko_When_They_Cry_episodes) on wikipedia. The plot summaries for the anime are all in the [fandom](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Umineko:_When_They_Cry_(anime)#List_of_Episodes). Just click on episode title, and voila.

For manga, there's a [list on the fandom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV57n.png), but...

While there are plot summaries for, like, [Legend of the Golden Witch Manga Volume 1: All Chapters 1-5](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/Legend_of_the_Golden_Witch_Manga_Volume_1#Chapters), there doesn't seem to be any for the answer arcs eg End of the Golden Witch: See [here for VN](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/End_of_the_Golden_Witch/Plot_Summary) and [here for manga](https://07th-expansion.fandom.com/wiki/End_of_the_Golden_Witch_Manga_Volume_1).

Comment: Why do you need summaries in the first place? There's no obligation to provide abridged versions of the series. Summaries and synopsis of these type of media often gloss over or leave out key details and context and are as reliable or unreliable as the writer makes themselves out to be. The complete VN is available for purchase download online. It's as a good of a place to start as any. Even if time is an issue, remember that time is whatever you make of it.

Comment: @кяαzєя I just figured they were lying about some place that I couldn't find. There are such summaries for the heavily criticised anime adaptation. Why not for the manga/VNs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something on tvtropes [Umineko Visual Novels : the Live But Delayed Blogination](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/lb_i.php?lb_id=12919198730B16280200&i_id=12919198730I16282000&p=1) by user [Jhiday](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Tropers/Jhiday). This I believe covers Arcs 1 to 7.